# How to use mysqli query using a separate connection.php file?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with mysqli. We know mysqli needs two parameter to execute. One is the "query" and other is the "php connection line code". Now, I want to make a separate connection file and want to write include "that separate connection file" in each file so that I do not need to write the connection code in each file or if I change the connection file, all files get the update.

But in that case, I will not have the connection line code in every file so I will have only one parameter to execute mysqli query so I will not be able to execute it. Any suggestions? I ignored code because Stack-overflow.com has too many restrictions on it.

Comment: If this site allows me to write code:   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","project"); this is the php connection line code ///                                                  mysqli_query($con,$check_exist); This is a two parameters query   ///                                                            I want to make a file with this line  : $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","project"); Save the file with the name connection.php and want to write this line in each php file include "connection.php"

Comment: You just ^^^^^^^^^^^ answered ^^^^^^^^^^^ your own question.

Comment: Oh, and it's `mysqli` and not `mysquli`, just so we set the record straight. I fixed your typos.

Answer (score 7):

`Mark B` did answer the question although his answer was for mysql -which is deprecated and shouldn't be used

by the way it is mysqli and not mysquli

Procedural style
let's say the connection file was:

**`conn.php`**

```
<?php
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
    if($mysqli_connect_error())
        die('Connect Error');
?>
```

and the other file:

**`other_file.php`**

```
<?php
    require 'conn.php';
    $res=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);    #yes $mysqli is available here although it is in another file
?>
```

OOP style

**`conn.php`**

```
<?php
    $mysqli=new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);
    if($mysqli->connect_error)
        die('Connect Error');
?>
```

and the other file:

**`other_file.php`**

```
<?php
    require 'conn.php';
    $res=$mysqli->query($query);
?>
```

Here I used the normal `mysqli::query` and `mysqli_query` (which are the same), but
I would also **recommend using prepared statements rather than `mysqli::query`** because it is safer for SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

IN simplified psuedo-code:

connection.php:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

any other script:

```
<?php

require('connection.php');

$stmt = mysql_query("SELECT ...", $con);
```

`require()` and `include()` act is if you'd literally cut & paste the included file into the file doing the including. There's no functional difference between

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect();
    mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

and

```
<?php
   include('file_that_connects_to_mysql.php');
   mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

As long as the file exists and can be included/required, it'll be as if you had its contents stuffed directly into the parent file.

Comment: OP did mispell *"I am having a problem with `mysquli`"* - so in most likeliness, should be `mysqli` - **Edit:** That's NOT my DV btw.

Comment: No, it's mine.  When people answer mysqli questions with `mysql_query`, the answer is simply broken.

Comment: I did say PSEUDO-code anyways. OP's apparently not familiar at all with PHP, otherwise they would already have known about include/require and could have done this themselves.

Comment: Thank You very much for the first answer!